Nav2 how to smooth velocities with deadband?
I'm having trouble with the cmd_vel that nav2 gives me for my robot. The robot only moves with :
angular speeds ∈ [-1rad/s, -0.3rad/s] ∪ [0.3rad/s, 1rad/s]
linear speeds ∈ [-1.2m/s, -0.3m/s] ∪ [0.3m/s, 1.2m/s]
Outside of these values the robot doesn't move at all due to constructor code and safety reasons. But the cmd_vel i receive is most of the time out of these values (between -0.3 and 0.3).
I saw that i could use the velocity_smoother node with
deadband_velocity: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
but this means all velocities under 0.3 rad/s or m/s will not be sent, doing so i can't ever have negative values. I would want to define a band between -0.3 and 0.3 that would be where velocities are blocked.
Can someone help me please ?
Thanks a lot in advance
